# Deletion of my account failed

Tags: bug, status-completed, deleted-accounts

I requested a deletion of this account: https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/users/50/empty

Mods put deletion in place and the 24 hour clock started.

I just logged back in and account is still there with the following status message:

> This account is scheduled to be deleted 8 mins **ago**. To cancel deletion, click here.

In other words the account is now 8 minutes past deletion date.

When will the account be deleted?

Comment: IIRC, we unleash the deathbots once every hour. Once they have annihilated the willing victims, they return to their cages until the next hour (edit: I'm not actually joking here... well, not about the hourly thing, at least; national security means I'm not allowed to confirm or deny the deathbots)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Erm. That's not supposed to happen. We don't run the check for this every minute, though, so it may just be delayed until the scheduled task that looks for these pending deletions executes.

Did you just cancel the deletion? I don't see a pending one on  your profile anymore.

---

Ah, it looks like you had enough reputation that your account was placed into a different queue. I'm processing the deletion right now. We might have a bug here, but there's no need to delay your case for that.

Comment: The deathbots have struck!  Thanks, I'm a little impatient sometimes.

Comment: @KevinJohnsrude that's a relief; I will await with anticipation the pending reincarnation - or have you now reached nirvana?